# Crash Reporting in SWIFT iOS

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, exception

Hello i am developing one ios application where i want to implement crashing reporting without using of any third party sdk or class i want to compose mail when my app will crash.
I have implemented `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandlerPtr)`
into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  and added Objective-C Code for its handler Here Code of my `CrashReporting`.h file

```
volatile void exceptionHandler(NSException *exception);
extern NSUncaughtExceptionHandler *exceptionHandlerPtr;
```

and CrashReporting.m Code:

```
volatile void exceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    // Do stuff

    NSLog(@"App IS cCrAsSHsED %@",exception.description);
    NSLog(@"App IS cCrAsSHsED %@",exception.callStackSymbols);

   // Here i will Compose mail with error description and callStackSymbols.
}
NSUncaughtExceptionHandler *exceptionHandlerPtr = &exceptionHandler;
```

Its works fine but its not able to handle all type errors. how can i do same for `Fatal Errors` and `Signal Errors` into swift i have searched on Google but nothing found helpful for swift. Help will be Appreciate.  Sorry for my bad english. Thanks.

Comment: Those error which leaves app in unstable state can't be reported through ios app .

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessary. It sounds to me that you just want to see the crash reports. Apple has already built the [Crash Report Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html) which will usually (if users did not deactivate it) deliver you the crash reports so you can analyze them.

Therefore it is not necessary to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I know this. You got me wrong. I want crash description via programmatically when app crash.

Comment: Well yes, but why do you want that? I am asking because I think it would help to understand what the specific problem is which you are trying to solve differently than Apple's crash reporter.